# Glyphicons not applying to my i class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I can't get glyphicons to apply to my i class. Not sure why. My code is:

My HTML is (reduced by 80% for test case):

```
<div id="categorymenu">
    <nav class="subnav">
        <ul id="nav" class="nav-pills categorymenu">
            <li><a href=" //rsatestamle.dminsite.com/CategoryList.aspx" title="Categories" alt="Categories">Categories <i class=".icon-arrow-down .icon-white"></i></a>
                <div>
                    <ul id="nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/made-in-the-u+s+a/c/USA_2012/">
                            Made in the USA</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href=" //rsatestamle.dminsite.com/brands.aspx" title="Brands" alt="Brands">Brands</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

My CSS is straight from Bootstrap.css (version 2.3.2) itself:

```
        [class^="icon-"],[class*=" icon-"]{display:inline-block;width:14px;height:14px;*margin-right:.3em;line-height:14px;vertical-align:text-top;background-image:url("http://cdnll.amleo.com/images/art/glyphicons-halflings.png");background-position:14px 14px;background-repeat:no-repeat;margin-top:1px;}
        .icon-white,.nav-pills>.active>a>[class^="icon-"],.nav-pills>.active>a>[class*=" icon-"],.nav-list>.active>a>[class^="icon-"],.nav-list>.active>a>[class*=" icon-"],.navbar-inverse .nav>.active>a>[class^="icon-"],.navbar-inverse .nav>.active>a>[class*=" icon-"],.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover>[class^="icon-"],.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus>[class^="icon-"],.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover>[class*=" icon-"],.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus>[class*=" icon-"],.dropdown-menu>.active>a>[class^="icon-"],.dropdown-menu>.active>a>[class*=" icon-"],.dropdown-submenu:hover>a>[class^="icon-"],.dropdown-submenu:focus>a>[class^="icon-"],.dropdown-submenu:hover>a>[class*=" icon-"],.dropdown-submenu:focus>a>[class*=" icon-"]{background-image:url("http://cdnll.amleo.com/images/art/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");}
        .icon-arrow-down{background-position:-312px -96px;}
```

However, the only style that's being applied is from my style.css http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/Styles/style.css

So I'm not sure how to even use the glyphicons at this point. I thought it'd be simple :/ Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Looked so easy.

Comment: remove the `.` from your class assignments - `class="icon-arrow-down"` != `class=".icon-arrow-down"`

Comment: Oh gosh darn it. I should've caught that. Thank you.